# Wix ProgressBar and UAC prompt

Tags: wix, uac

I have created application installer using Wix. I have a ProgressBar control present on the screen with copying files etc. When UAC is enabled, after this screen appeared, it freezed for a 10 or more seconds and then UAC prompt is displayed : "Do you want to allow the following program to install software on this computer?".

My question is:
how to make progress bar move during waiting for UAC prompt to be displayed? Or how to force UAC to be shown faster (< 5 seconds)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the only approach that will help is splitting your installer into several exes (or a mixture of exes and whatever.) I find that the pause before the first UAC screen depends on the size of the exe. Everything launched from an elevated process is elevated, so if you could get a small bootstrapper going, it should pop the UAC quite quickly, then you can launch the rest from that.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider that.